# Silverlight CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess() - how does it know?

Tags: silverlight, permissions, capture

`CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess()` method must be invoked by user interaction, otherwise it fails. My question is how does Silverlight know the invocation came from user (i.e. via `Button.Click()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://liviutrifoi.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/silverlight-isolatedstoragefile-increasequotato/

Quote:

> I was curios though how exactly does silverlight know what a user
>   initiated event is, but after digging through .net framework source
>   code I’ve got to a dead end:

```
if ((browserService == null) || !browserService.InPrivateMode())
{
    //..
}
return false; //means that IncreaseQuota will fail
where browser.IsInPrivateMode is:

[SecuritySafeCritical]
public bool InPrivateMode()
{
    bool privateMode = false;
    return (NativeMethods.SUCCEEDED(UnsafeNativeMethods.DOM_InPrivateMode(this._browserServiceHandle, out privateMode)) && privateMode);
}
```

> where DOM_InPrivateMode is in a DllImport["agcore"], which according
>   to microsoft is confidential :( So it looks like I won’t find out soon
>   how they’re detecting user initiated events, although I’m guessing
>   they have some centralized private method that detects clicks for
>   example, and then probably sets a flag that this was indeed “a user
>   initiated event”, and since you can’t forge clicks or keypresses using
>   javascript and since you can’t call those private methods using
>   reflection, it’s “safe”.